# perl rmtree throwing empty exception

Tags: perl

I'm having this very weird where i'm using rmtree("C:\myfolder"); and it's throwing some kind of exception but it is doing what it is supposed to.

I have this enclosed in

```
eval {
  rmtree("C:\myfolder");
};
if($@) {
   print $@;
}
```

If the folder exists I get an exception thrown eventhough the folder is succesfully deleted. The thrown exception is blank nothing at all. I even tried setting rmtree("C:\myfolder", {verbose => 1}) in rmtree but same thing.

My current hack is to do

```
eval {
   eval {
  rmtree("C:\myfolder");
  };
};
if($@) {
   print $@;
}
```

Comment: If `$@` was "blank", the `if` wold never trigger, but you seem to say it does?

Comment: The `if` will never trigger in your second snippet, since the outer eval will never catch an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you detect a blank exception??

From [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html#ERROR-HANDLING):

```
remove_tree( 'foo/bar', 'bar/rat', {error => \my $err} );
if (@$err) {
    for my $diag (@$err) {
        my ($file, $message) = %$diag;
        if ($file eq '') {
            print "general error: $message\n";
        }
        else {
            print "problem unlinking $file: $message\n";
        }
    }
}
else {
    print "No error encountered\n";
}
```

In Windows, I know that relative paths work with `/`. I think absolute paths work with `/` too!

```
remove_tree("C:/myfolder"); #this should work
```

Answer (score 2):

try escaping the backslash ie.

> "C:\\myfolder"